# How do I open a doc or pdf file from php if i have the url using word?

Tags: php, pdf, doc

I have a php application with a link that points to .doc and pdf files within my computer. I want to click the links and then open the file with office word or pdf reader.

```
echo "<a href=\"temp\/es\/doc1.pdf\">Open</a>";
```

Comment: PHP has no control over what software is on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome on Stackoverflow, what u're asking it's not php-related for what i can understand. Your link is build correctly (as long as the path actually exist).

The expected output you're asking it's all about you operating system preferences. For example if you are using Google Chrome you can expect the pdf file to be opened directly inside the browser.